# Infimum of $\max(0,y) + \frac{1}{2t}(x-y)^2$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, supremum-and-infimum, maxima-minima

I want to compute the Moreau Envelope of the function $f(y) = \max(0,y)$. 
I know that the Moreau Envelope is given by:

$f_t(x) = \inf_y \{ f(y) + \frac{1}{2t}(x-y)^2 \ | y \in \mathbb{R} \}$

In our case this is:

$f_t(x) = \inf_y \{ \max(0,y) + \frac{1}{2t}(x-y)^2 | y \in \mathbb{R} \}$

Now everything left is computing the infimum. However, somehow I am messing up this step.

I thought about a case distinction with:

- $y < 0$
- $y > 0$
- $y = 0$

But this led to nowhere. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Assuming $t>0$.

If $x\le 0$, the infimum is attained when $y=x$, then we have $$f_t(x)=0.$$

Now, we focus on the case where $x>0$,

If $y \le 0$, $\max(0,y)+\frac1{2t}(x-y)^2=\frac1{2t}(x-y)^2 \ge \frac{x^2}{2t}$

For $y\ge 0$, notice that it is a trade off between the the norm of $y$ and the approximation of $x$. If $y>x$, we could have find a better solution that is less than $x$ and have a smaller norm in $y$. To be explicit, the expression is evaluate to be $$y+\frac1{2t}(x-y)^2$$

which is a quadratic equation subject to the constraint that $y > 0$. Try to find the minimal of this problem.

Edit：

\begin{align}y + \frac1{2t}(x-y)^2 &=\frac1{2t}(x^2-2xy+y^2+2ty)\\
&=\frac1{2t}(y^2+2(t-x)y+x^2)\\
&=\frac1{2t}\left((y+(t-x))^2+x^2-(t-x)^2\right)\\
&=\frac1{2t}\left((y+(t-x))^2-t^2+2tx\right)\\
&=\frac1{2t}((y-(x-t))^2-\frac{t}2+x\end{align}

$\max(0,y)+\frac{1}{2t}(x-y)^2$ is a continuous function in $y$, when $x-t>0$, the minimal is attained there, and the minimal value is $x-\frac{t}2$. Otherwise, the minimal is attained when $y=0$ with value $\frac{x^2}{2t}.$

Comment: I don't get how you get the separation of $x<=0$ and $x>0$.

Comment: I just consider cases, first I consider what happens if $x \le 0$, then I consider what happens if $x>0$.

Comment: Ok, my end result is $ 
    f_t(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        x-t/2, & \text{for } x > t\\
        0 & \text{for } x < 0\\
        \frac{1}{2t}x^2 & \text{else}
        \end{array}\right\} 
  $ - can this be correct?

Comment: congratulatinos.

Comment: thank you, now I understand how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Below is my attempt:

---

Both summands in the expression $\, \max\left(0,y\right)+ \frac{1}{2t}(x-y)^2  $ are non-negative, thus the infimum is reached when both of them are minimized.
The first term is obviously minimized by $y=0$, and the second is by $y=x$.
Since you need the infimum expressed as function of $x$, you can compute derivative

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}\left[\max\left(0,y\right)+ \frac{\left(x-y\right)^2}{2t} \right] = \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}\left[\max\left(0,y\right) \right] + \frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}\left[\frac{\left(x-y\right)^2}{2t}\right]
$$

$$
\max\left(0,y\right) = \cases{0,\quad y \le 0 \\y,  \quad y>0 } 
\implies
\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}\left[\max\left(0,y\right) \right]  = \cases{0,\quad y \le 0 \\1,  \quad y>0 } 
$$

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}\left[\frac{\left(x-y\right)^2}{2t}\right]=\frac{y-x}{t}
$$

thus

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}\left[\max\left(0,y\right)+ \frac{\left(x-y\right)^2}{2t} \right] 
=\cases{0+\left(y-x\right)/t,\quad y \le 0 \\1+\left(y-x\right)/t,  \quad y>0 } 
$$

The first naive approach I want to try is to set derivatives to zero and compute extrema of 
$$
f_t\left(x\right) = \inf_y \left\lbrace \max\left(0,y\right) + \frac{\left(x-y\right)^2}{2t} \mid y \in \mathbb{R} \right\rbrace
$$

as following:

$$
0=\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}\big[\max\left(0,y\right)+ \frac{\left(x-y\right)^2}{2t} \big] =\cases{0+\left(y-x\right)/t,\quad y \le 0 \\1+\left(y-x\right)/t,  \quad y>0 } 
\implies
\cases{y_0=x,&$y\le0$\\y_0=x-t,&$y>0$}
$$

Thus we get

$$
f_t\left(x\right) = \inf_y \left\lbrace \max\left(0,y\right) + \frac{\left(x-y\right)^2}{2t} \mid y \in \mathbb{R} \right\rbrace
{\stackrel{?}{=}}
\left.\left(\max\left(0,y\right) + \frac{\left(x-y\right)^2}{2t}  \right)\right\rvert_{y=y_0}
$$

$$
f_t\left(x\right) = \cases{
0, & $y\le0$
\\
\max\left(0,x-t\right) + \frac{t}{2}  , & $y>0$}
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Problem with this solutuon is that $y$ is not an argument of the final function any more. So the case distinction does not make sense.

Comment: @今天春天 Since $f_t(x)$ is _defined_ as the ___infimum over $y$___ of some expression depending on $(x,y)$, it is quite expected that the result (infimum) will not depend of $y$. In fact, it would be very weird if it ___did___ depend of $y$. Consider the following analogy: if you have function of single variable $f(x)$ and compute _infimum_ (or _minimum_) of $f$ over $x$, then the result should not depend on $x$, because by definition infimum captures lower boundary among _all admissible values_ of variable $x$.